# grep, Extracting A Subset Of Sequences from fasta file based on word in id line

Tags: perl, grep, extract, fasta

I know there are question *like* this one but this is slightly different. I want to extract a subset of sequences from a fasta file based on a word in id line and put those found into new file. I tried

```
grep -E 'Eukaryota' test_db.fasta > new.fa
```

but this only gave me the identifier line that contained the word. I need the sequence also. The length of the sequence varies.

Any ideas how to alter my command or maybe a Perl solution?

Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear (atleast to me !). Kindly provide some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Sample data is needed for those of us that have no idea what fasta formatted data looks like.

Comment: Have you tried looking at all the other questions on SO that have been tagged with [tag:fasta]?  There are many questions from your bio brethren that will probably get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BioPerl is nice for doing such things.

This little script will do the job :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $seqIOin  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-format => 'fasta', -file => "<fasta_to_filter.fa");
my $seqIOout = Bio::SeqIO->new(-format => 'fasta', -file => ">selected_sequences.fa");

while (my $seq = $seqIOin->next_seq){
    $seqIOout->write_seq($seq) if ($seq->id =~ /YOUR_WORD/);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple Awk one-liner.

```
awk '/^>/ { p = ($0 ~ /Eukaryota/)} p' test_db.fasta>new.fa
```

This looks for "Eukaryota" on any line starting with a `>`. If it is found, `p` is set to 1, otherwise to 0. If `p` is non-zero, print the line.